Using Foreign Function and Memory API with bit offsets instead of BitSet
I would like to define a MemoryLayout from the Panama API in JDK 22 with bit offsets. ValueLayouts like ValueLayout.JAVA_BYTE seem to only be usable with a byte granularity, which doesn't fit my use case.
I wanted to use the Panama API to load a byte[] and access specific values according to a scheme, that for example defines that there is a value between bit 3 and 6 and another value between bit 7 and 9, and so on. When checking the JDK 18 incubator documentation of MemoryLayout there are functions referring bitOffset instead of byteOffset.
Currently I am using a BitSet to interpret the scheme, but I was looking forward to using a more direct approach. Is this not supported anymore or am I missing something?

No, the JDK 22 API does not offer any functions supporting individual by-bit offsets.

Is there a reason known on why they changed this? Neither the mail archive of Panama nor Google is really turning up anything about this change...

@user26818258 We never had an API to access bit fields (memory is typically byte-addressable, so bit-sized access would have to be emulated). While it was possible to define a layout with bit-sized fields, you couldn't really do anything with them. So, this was eventually streamlined out of the API. See some of the background here: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/14013
